# How to find youtube video as HD/NEW/3D movies using the Youtube API json not through javascript API/xml api?

Tags: youtube-api, gdata

I saw in my web search they are retriving `hd`, `3d`, `new` and video filters(left side bottom), I need the same kind of feature.

> search.mywebsearch.com/mywebsearch/video.jhtml?searchfor=ipod

Is is possible to get the search filters, `hd`, `3d`, `new` using youtube `jsonc`?

Answer (score 0):

Why you didn't do like that?

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=birds&alt=jsonc&prettyprint=True&hd=true&3d=true&orderby=published&v=2

Cheers

Comment: I am not specifically looking to filter the data. For example if I search for "ipod" and in the results I see each video indicated either its HD or 3d or New.

Comment: As indicated https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/aVTST13pVF8,

i think you should using json, https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=birds&prettyprint=True&hd=true&3d=true&orderby=published&v=2&alt=json&time=this_week,
so you can see yt$threed if it's 3d, "yt$hd": {} if it's hd, no return these key if it's not 3d/hd.

"new" key? You should handle on your side, not API side. Whether you query with time=today/this_week/.. is your code side.

Comment: Compare date by your code logic and label as "new", there's no such "yt$newVideo" key.